# Ionic firebase onAuthStateChanged doesn't trigger until I click in a form

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I'm building an app that has a user login to Facebook using firebase and I can get the email login to work automatically, but the Facebook login returns me to the Login page and waits until I click in the form before it detects that the auth has changed.

In **app.component.ts** I'm detecting the user change with:

```
const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged( user => {
  if (!user) {
    this.rootPage = 'LoginPage';
    unsubscribe();
  } else { 
    this.rootPage = 'HomePage';
    unsubscribe();
  }
});
```

In **login.ts** I'm performing the login with the following code (which never changes my root to HomePage):

```
facebookLogin() {
    this.authData.signInWithFacebook().then( res => {
      this.navCtrl.setRoot('HomePage');
    }, error => {
      //this.loading.dismiss().then( () => {
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          message: error,
          buttons: [
            {
              text: "Ok",
              role: 'cancel'
            }
          ]
        });
        alert.present();
      //});
    });
  }
```

And in auth.ts I'm performing the login with:

```
signInWithFacebook(): Promise<any> {
    if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
      return this.facebook.login(['email']).then( res => {
        const facebookCredential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(res.authResponse.accessToken);
        firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential).then( (success) => {
          console.log("Firebase success: " + JSON.stringify(success));
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("Firebase failure: " + JSON.stringify(error));
        });
      });
    }
    else {
      return firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider())
    }
  }
}
```

My best guess is that there is a delay for the authorization to occur so when I return to the login page it waits there until the authorization completes.

**What I don't understand is why it isn't checking for the authorization until I click on the screen.**

**Edit:** 
Console outputs the following after I click on the Login with Facebook button and run `facebookLogin()`:

> [09:53:03]  console.log: Angular is running in the development mode.
>   Call enableProdMode() to enable the production
>               mode. [09:53:03]  console.log: ionViewDidLoad LoginPage [09:53:03]  console.warn: Native: tried calling
>   StatusBar.styleDefault, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to
>               include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator [09:53:04]  console.warn: Native: tried calling SplashScreen.hide, but Cordova is
>   not available. Make sure to include
>               cordova.js or run in a device/simulator

**Edit 2**
I've added a console log to check where I'm getting to. When I login with redirect (on a browser) the page goes back to the app.components.ts and detects that a user has changed...but the page doesn't move until I click on an element such as the form.

```
constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, 
    splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    //const authObserver = afAuth.authState.subscribe( user => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged( user => {
      if (!user) {
        console.log('User auth state changed. Log them out.')
        this.rootPage = 'LoginPage';
        unsubscribe();
      } else { 
        //var currentState = $ionicHistory.currentStateName();
        console.log('User auth state changed. Send onwards.') // This runs.
        this.rootPage = 'HomePage'; // This doesn't run until I click an element.
        unsubscribe();
      }
    });
```

Comment: do you get an error in console? i.e. does it go to catch in your `facebookLogin` function?

Comment: Added console log to my original question. Only error I get is that Angular is running in development mode. Otherwise the warnings are about cordova status bar.

Comment: so is it going to the if part or else in your function? are you doing `ionic serve` or running in device?

Comment: It looks like there is a delay in running `this.rootPage = 'HomePage';`. I made some changes and it runs much faster with `this.nav.setRoot('HomePage');`. I had to add some other code to activate NavController on the page first.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have missed returning the innermost promise which means in the `signInWithFacebook` function, the innermost promise `signInWithCredential` is executed *after* `signInWithFacebook` has already returned.

```
 return this.facebook.login(['email']).then( res => {
        const facebookCredential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(res.authResponse.accessToken);
//add return below
        return firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential).then( (success) => {
          console.log("Firebase success: " + JSON.stringify(success));
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("Firebase failure: " + JSON.stringify(error));
        });
     });
```

Comment: Thanks. Fixed this and also fixed where I was forgetting to check for the results of the redirect. `return firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then( res => { console.log(res); })`. But no dice. Adding some console logs I found out that the page is detecting the user is logged in..but for some reason this.root = 'HomePage' isn't running until I click the page.